# How to sort by nested objects integer field

Tags: django, sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to get elasticsearch docs sorted by price. I have this docs:

```
class OfferDocument(InnerDoc):
     partner_price = Float()

class ProductDocument(DocType):
     view_count = Integer()
     offers = Nested(OfferDocument)
```

So, I have 55000 products in elasticsearch and I have to get them sorted by its offers price. So what I did:
        `s = ProductDocument.search().query(some_query).sort({'offers.partner_price':{'order':'asc', 'mode': 'min'}})`
When I do:
        `s = ProductDocument.search().query(some_query).sort({'view_count':{'order':'desc'}})`
It sorts correct. But It sorts incorrectly with nested object offer and its field partner_price. What's my problem?